# Duplicate Unique IDs add letter to each

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT                             
t1.[ACCEPT] + t1.[Price] + RIGHT(t1.[CARD],4) as 't1.UniqueID',
t2.[Approval Code] + t2.[Price] + RIGHT(t2.[Card Number],4) as 't2.UniqueID'
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
table2 t2 ON 
(t1.ACCEPT + t1.Price + RIGHT(t1.[CARD],4)) = 
(t2.[Approval Code] + t2.[Price] + RIGHT(t2.[Card Number],4))
```

I join two tables together as shown above, this is the only way I create a unique ID to link the two tables.
However, on very rare circumstances there are duplicates of this ID

Is there any way I can run a sql query that will find the duplicates and add a letter on the end

e.g. lets say there were 3 duplicates (this is very, very rare and might not happen but for arguments sake)

```
t1.UniqueID        t2.UniqueID
00012136.006521    00012136.006521
00012136.006521    00012136.006521
00012136.006521    00012136.006521
```

I is there a way I can loop through and add a letter on to the ids for both tables

```
t1.UniqueID        t2.UniqueID
00012136.006521a    00012136.006521a
00012136.006521b    00012136.006521b
00012136.006521c    00012136.006521c
```

Thanks for any help, really stuck with this

Comment: I think you need to remove the quotes on the 2nd and 3rd line before the comma in your SQL?

Comment: Why would you EVER wanna join on these columns? Further, the `SELECT` and `JOIN` do not show the same columns selected. E.g. `t1.[Approval Code]` in SELECT and `t1.ACCEPT` in JOIN.

Comment: @NickyvV was a typo sorry!

Comment: @NickyvV also I join them on these columns because it creates a uniqueID..

Answer (score 1):

small example,

```
Declare @t table(UniqueID varchar(50))
insert into @t values('00012136.006521'),('00012136.006521')

;with cte as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by UniqueID) rn  from @t)

select UniqueID+char(97+(rn-1)) from cte
```

can you implement this in your query ?

Comment: thanks for your reply but would this actually update the table and insert the character?

Comment: do you want to update the table ?or just view ?
show what you have done ?where you are struck ?